# basic_ifstream<...>::read() doesn't read anything

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, stream, gcc4.9

The program built from this code:

```
#include <fstream>
using std::basic_ifstream;

#include <ios>
using std::streamsize;

#include <ZenLib/Conf.h>
using ZenLib::int8u;

int main() {
#define charT int8u
#define T basic_ifstream<charT>
    T ifs ("/proc/cpuinfo", T::in | T::binary);
#undef T
    streamsize const bufsize (4096);
    charT buf[bufsize];
#undef charT
    return !ifs.read(buf, bufsize).gcount();
}
```

... returns 1.

So `std::basic_ifstream<ZenLib::int8u>::read()` could not extract any byte from `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Can you synthesize a simple, self-contained example that doesn't require chasing through multiple macros?

Comment: The streams are designed to be used with character types as template parameters, not integers.

Comment: Streams only support the character types `char` and `wchar_t`. This isn't guaranteed to work for different character types because of a lack of a specialized code conversion facet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intantiating `std::char_traits` for anything but `char` or `wchar_t` is
undefined behavior (And I suspect that your `charT` is `unsigned char`,
not `char`.)  If you want to use a different type for characters, you'll
have to define a new traits class; for `std::istream` anf
`std::ostream`, you'll also have to define a number of facets for the
type as well.

The question is what you want to do.  In your example, you only call
`std::istream::read`.  If this is the case, the simplest solution is
probably to just drop down to the system level functions.  These
probably want a `char*` for there buffer as well, but a
`reinterpret_cast` from `unsigned char*` will work.  You can do this for
`std::istream<char>::read` as well, but if you have an `std::istream`,
there's a definite possibility that some formatted input will creap in,
and that will interpret the characters before you can get your
`reinterpret_cast` in.

Comment: I’d like to use `MediaInfoLib::MediaInfo::Open_Buffer_Continue()` which accepts `const ZenLib::int8u` as buffer’s char’s type.

Answer (score 2):

The stream libraries are designed to be used with the character types such as `char` and `wchar_t`, not integers:

**C++11 standard: 27.2.2**

> 2. In the classes of Clause 27, a template formal parameter with name
>      charT represents a member of the set of types containing char,
>      wchar_t, and any other implementation-defined character types that
>      satisfy the requirements for a character on which any of the iostream
>      components can be instantiated.

Maybe start from this:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("/proc/cpuinfo", std::ios::binary);
    std::cout << ifs.rdbuf();
}
```